# Improve aggregation of data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have `data.table` looking like this:

```
dt <- data.table(
  a   = c( "A", "B", "C", "C" ),
  b   = c( "U", "V", "W", "X" ),
  c   = c( 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ),
  min = c( 0,   1,   2,   3 ),
  max = c( 11,  12,  13,  14 ),
  val = c( 100, 200, 300, 400 ),
  key = "a"
)
```

My actual `data.table` has much more columns and up to a couple of million rows. About 10% of the rows have a duplicated key `a`. Those rows I'd like to aggregate with a function looking like this one:

```
comb <- function( x ){
  k <- which.max( x[ ,c ]  )
  list( b = x[ k, b ], c = x[ k, c ], min = min( x[ , min ] ), max = max( x[ , max ] ), val = sum( x[ ,val ] ) )
}
```

However, calling

```
dt <- dt[ , comb(.SD), by = a ]
```

is very slow and I'm wondering how I could improve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Two ideas: Use `if`/`else` in your function to check if `nrow(x)>1` and only do all those calculations if that's the case. And I believe `dt[,list(b=b[which.max(c)],c=max(c),min=min(min),max=max(max),val=sum(val)),by=a]` should be faster than working with `.SD` here.

Comment: @Roland the reason why I capsule that in a function is, because in my real example, I need the value of `which.max(c)` multiple times. I'm afraid if I call `dt[ , list( ... ) ]` I'd have to put `which.max(c)`everywhere where I need it's value?

Comment: Yes, you would. I cannot really test alternatives for performance with you example. Can you provide a (much) bigger toy data.table that reflects the ratio of unique key values to total rows?

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I'll do some benchmarking on my own and present the results later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By placing `c` in the key and using `.N` to get the maximum we can avoid `which.max` (untested):

```
setkey(dt, a, c)
dt[, c(.SD[.N], min = min[1], val = sum(val)), by = a][, -c(4, 6)]
```

ADDED: or this variation:

```
dt[, c(.SD[.N, c(1:2, 4)], min = min[1], val = sum(val)), by = a]
```

ADDED 2: We only used `.SD` because you indicated you had many columns but if you are willing to write them out then the above could be written:

```
dt[, list(b = b[.N], c = c[.N], min = min[1], max = max[.N], val = sum(val)), by = a]
```

ADDED 3: Yet another variation:

```
dt[, c("min", "val") := list(min[1], sum(val)), by = a][, .SD[.N], by = a]
```

### Benchmarks

Microbenchmarking the four solutions gave the following boxplot (n = 10):

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why, but the c( .SD[.N], ... ) seems to be quite expensive as my microbenchmarks show. But using `.N` instead of `which.max` in @Rolands comment is a great idea which gives me at the moment the best results.